# How do I smoothly hide a view on RecyclerView scoll?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have a RecylcerView and a view which is above it and I want to hide it when I scroll down. I have found a way which kind of works, but it's pretty janky and sometimes takes the speed out of the scrolling action. How do I make it more fluent?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.Items.ItemsFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardViewSearch">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


        android:id="@+id/recylcerViewItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chipGroup" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardViewSearch">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/toolsChip"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            android:text="@string/item_tools"
            android:textColor="@color/colorChipText"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorChipTools"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_tool_black_24dp"
            app:chipIconTint="@color/colorChipText" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/blocksChip"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            android:text="@string/item_blocks"
            android:textColor="@color/colorChipText"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorChipBlocks"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_block_black_24dp"
            app:chipIconTint="@color/colorChipText" />

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

</FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to hide the ChipGroup. There are more Chips in the group, but I removed them here.

Hide Code right now:

```
    final ChipGroup chipGroup = (ChipGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.chipGroup);
    mRecyclerView.setPadding(0, chipGroup.getHeight(), 0,0);

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                if(!showFilteredResults) {
                    showFilteredResults = true;
                }
            } else {
                if(showFilteredResults) {
                    showFilteredResults = false;
                }
            }
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
            if (dy > 0 && HIDE_VIEWS_ON_SCOLL) {
                // scrolling up
                Log.i("scroll", "up");
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(frameLayout, new ChangeBounds());
                chipGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mRecyclerView.setPadding(0, 0,0,0);
            } else if (dy < 0 && HIDE_VIEWS_ON_SCOLL){
                // scrolling down
                Log.i("scroll", "down");
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(frameLayout, new ChangeBounds());
                chipGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRecyclerView.setPadding(0, chipGroup.getHeight(),0,0);
            }

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use YoYo library from github have all animation and very easy to use
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

You can use this any where

Simple use it inside onscrollchanged method of recyclerview